Clarification on 7 Wonders Pantheon Ra Steal Wonder Power
Checking on a detail on Ra steal wonder power. So, you snag a wonder of your choice. Do you then place it amongst your unbuilt wonders? In other words, I assume  it is not correct to place it into play for free.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You place it amongst your unbuilt Wonders without constructing it.
In the rule book for 7 Wonders Duel Pantheon on page 12 the instructions for the Ra power card state:
"Steal an opponent’s Wonder which has not yet been constructed; it is added to your own Wonders."
To add to your own Wonders means to place it with your Wonders and it becomes one of your unbuilt Wonders. It does not say to construct that Wonder (for free or by paying it's cost).
